# $AB, AB^*, A^*B \leq G$ with $A^* \leq A \leq G$, $B^* \leq B \leq G$ $\Rightarrow$ $AB=(AB^*)(A^*B)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $A^* \leq A \leq G$, $B^* \leq B \leq G$.

*If $AB$, $AB^*$, $A^*B$ are all subgroups of $G$, is it true that $AB=(AB^*)(A^*B)$?*

I tried to prove the double inclusion of sets: $AB \subseteq (AB^*)(A^*B)$ because an element $ab \in AB$ can be written as $ab=(a \cdot 1)(1 \cdot b)$.
Conversely, let $(ab^*)(a^*b)$ be an element of $(AB^*)(A^*B)$. Since $AB^*= B^*A$ and $A^*B=BA^*$, there exsist $b_1, \bar{b}, b_2 \in B$, $a_1^* \in A^*$, $a_2, a_3 \in A$ such that

\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
(ab^*)(a^*b) &= (ab^*)(b_1a_1^*) \\
&= a(b^*b_1)a_1^* \\
&= (a \bar{b})a_1^* \\
&= b_2(a_2a_1^*) \\
&= b_2a_3 \in BA=AB
\end{split}
\end{align*}
so $(AB^*)(A^*B) \subseteq AB$.

It could go well? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Given subgroups $H$ and $K$, $HK$ is a subgroup if and only if $HK=KH$ as sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [@ArturoMagidin's hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4755861/ab-ab-ab-leq-g-with-a-leq-a-leq-g-b-leq-b-leq-g-rightarr?noredirect=1#comment10095023_4755861) . . .

Since $AB^*$ is a subgroup, $AB^*=B^*A$, so that

$$(AB^*)(A^*B)=(B^*A)(A^*B).$$

But set product is associative, so we have

$$(AB^*)(A^*B)=B^*((AA^*)B).$$

Now $A^*\le A$ implies $AA^*=A$, giving

$$(AB^*)(A^*B)=B^*(AB).$$

Since $AB$ is a subgroup, $AB=BA$, so $B^*\le B$ implying $B^*B=B$ gives

$$(AB^*)(A^*B)=AB.$$

Comment: Thank you! From what I see , it looks like my reasoning but this is done directly on the sets and not explicitly on the elements :)

Comment: You're welcome, @Brendon. Indeed, yes. You had the right idea. Also, please don't forget to accept this answer if it works for you.